# is there any better way to handel IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

```
int sum(int[] arr,int size,int suma){
  if(size < 0) return suma; 

   return   sum(arr,size-1, suma+arr[size]);
}
```

This code works fine as it breaks when the size is less than zero, but also give `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException : Invalid array index: -1` while debugging.
what else I can do to avoid this `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the problem: the code works, correct?

Comment: add an `if (size < 0) return 0`? If you don't want arguments to have certain properties, check for them first, and then either return "what makes sense", or throw an appropriate exception.

Comment: @BrunoGavaGuerra yes it's work fine but Just wanted to know is there any better way to write it? for me this code is like "to kill a fish, break the aquarium pot". is there other way around?

Comment: @user16320675 thanks. I'm learning Dp. so have to do every-bit of thing in recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum array's index is `0`, so you should at last add `arr[length - 1]` to the final sum. Therefore you should stop the recursion if the length is `0`;

```java
public static int sum(int[] arr, int length, int sum) {
    return length < 1? sum : sum(arr, length - 1, sum + arr[length - 1]);
}
```

Demo:

```java
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
System.out.println(sum(arr, arr.length, 1000)); // 1021
```

Comment: I don't recommend looking for length ==0
if someone accidentally puts in a negative number for the length then you'll get an infinite recursion (stack overflow)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```java
public static int sum(int[] arr,int size,int suma){
   if (size < 1) return suma; 

   return   sum(arr,size-1, suma+arr[size-1]);
}
```

The index should never be equal to the size anyway since indexes start from 0.

Comment: but wont be able to access the element at arr[0]

Comment: just fixed it. should work now

Comment: @user16320675 size = arr.length

Comment: @DARKFOREST as the code is now. If size is 0, it will return suma (presumably you start suma == 0, when you call it
If size is 1, then the if statement will fail and it will compute:
sum(arr, 0, 0 + arr[0]) 

Which will make suma 0+arr[0]. What you want.

Comment: An example with size 2:
sum({2,3}, 2, 0)
becomes: sum({2,3}, 1, 0+2)
becomes: sum({2,3}, 0, 0+2+3)
which becomes: 5

Perfect tail recursion.